# Minecraft 1.12 - Automatic crops farm Pressure plate issues

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I built an automatic potatoes farm but the potato block that is supposed to be popping out on stone pressure plate activate isnt popping out even thou the light level is 8 block 7 light.

Here is a screenshot of the debug menu, in 1.9 it used to work.

[image: ssc1]
[image: ssc2]

I've made sure the light is below 9, I tried replanting the crop and I tried using different pressure plates still no effect.

Any idea why it doesn't work in 1.12?

Comment: You know potatoes only grow up right? They dont grow out like pumpkins or watermelons. So none of them will ever grow over the pressure plate. Not sure if thats what you were trying to have happen, but it will never happen that way.

Comment: pressing the pressure plate causes a block update which then causes the potato to pop out since it doesn't have enough light. That's the theory of it at least,

Comment: Do you have a tutorial link for this, a video, or have you personally seen it work?  In any version?  So the intention is to step on the plate and have the potatoes around the plate harvest?  It sounded as though you were expecting the potato plant to spread and grow out from under the pressure plate at first.

Comment: Interesting, Im not sure I can help you much more. Whenever I build farms, I always look at youtube videos and find builds I like. I never try to do my own because I just dont understand redstone well enough. :p For your reference, [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rxbBxXAT_us) is an excellent version of a fully automatic farms that uses a villager to plant things for you!

Comment: Does a video of what you're trying to donexist or can you make one?

Comment: https://youtu.be/-BIrqPH4Jfk?t=4m59s
Unarybit's 1.9 design explains why and how it works the pressure plate method

Comment: YouTube: [Simplified Unarybit's Villager Crop Farm for Minecraft 1.12+ Single Villager Needed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q1DhXJho2cY)

Comment: Christ I guess the plate design has been nerfed for 1.9 ++ ... well anyway simpler is better :D so thanks for the video, you can post it as an answer and I will accept it for you ,just make sure you note that the 1.9 design is out-of-date and the new design should be used.

Comment: I will post an answer.  Before I do, I am going to build and fully understand both designs so I can give more detail then just posting a video.

Comment: @IronAnvil Reminder, you said you wanted to post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Potato blocks do not exist. When the potato plant has a bit of yellow at the bottom, you break it to get potatoes.

Comment: He knows that. But block updates break potatoes